# SSRS - Group by week

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have a report that displays work hours from a start date parameter to an end date parameter. I'm struggling grouping the dates of the work hours by week. Below is a screenshot of how my report currently looks like:

[image]

How can I group the dates by week? In other words, how can I divide the above list into two, from 12/7/2020 - 12/11/2020 and 12/14/2020 - 12/18/2020? I already tried grouping by `=DatePart("ww", Fields!EntryDate.Value)` but then it only displays the first day of that week.

Edit: Even if I add a field that contains the week number of the EntryDate via SQL and group by that value, I only get the first date of the week.

As requested, here is the design of the report with its fields and a mock up of the final designing that I want to achieve.

[image]

Comment: Can you show a mock up of what you want to see in the final output based on your sample above. Also, please share the current report design including row groups. What you are attempting to do is correct approach so it's hard to know what's wrong without this extra info.

Comment: Where are you grouping by the Week? It should be in the **table1_FullName** group to match the mock-up. The **DateEntry** group should be grouped by just **EntryDate**.

Comment: right-click the DateEntry group and add a parent group, include totals. Set the group expression to the expression you already tried. If you still have a week grouping in any other row group, remove these. That should get you close.

Comment: @AlanSchofield, adding a parent group to the EntryDate group and putting the calculated week number as the expression solved my problem. Post the comment as an answer so I can mark it solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click the DateEntry group and add a parent group, include totals.

Set the group expression to the calculated week number expression you already tried.

If you still have week grouping in any other row groups, remove these. That should get you close